# Constraint Violation in Sampling Period in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I was working with the Twitter API and working on a data analysis project of sentiment analysis where I uploaded my data on GridDB and wrote a TQL query to extract the number of tweets after 1st January 2022 till date categorized according to the hour, which is as follows:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', created_at) as day,
       count(*) as num_tweets
FROM tweets
WHERE created_at >= '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY day, extract(hour from created_at)
ORDER BY day;
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
[Server]: 60151

[Description] (Unit of period is out of the support range)
```

I am unable to resolve this error because hour and day are the units used in the Time series function. Any ideas as to why this error is occurring?